# Sending multiple rows to XML and creating multiple nodes

Tags: sql, xml

Given the following sample table structures:

```
Table Customer:
CustomerID varchar(50),
CustomerName varchar(50)

Sample Data:
Customer ID   CustomerName
ABC123        Joe Sample

Table Phone:
CustomerID varchar(50),
PhoneNumber varchar(50),
PhoneType  varchar(50)

Sample Data:
CustomerID        PhoneNumber          PhoneType
ABC123            602-100-2000         Home
ACB123            602-200-1234         Cell
```

How would one using TSQL to create the following XML

```
<Customer>
  <CustomerID>ABC123</CustomerID>
  <CustomerName>Joe Sample</CustomerName>
  <Phones>
    <Phone>
      <PhoneNumber>602-100-2000</PhoneNumber>
      <PhoneType>Home</PhoneType>
    </Phone>
    <Phone>
      <PhoneNumber>602-200-1234</PhoneNumber>
      <PhoneType>Cell</PhoneType>
    </Phone>
   </Phones>
</Customer>
```

This is a vastly simplified example from the data set and structure I'm using but most of the approaches I've tried don't seem to be creating the repeating nodes properly.  When I join the tables ahead of output they tend to create multiple instances of the customer record.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

After spending some more time it appears that one can specify the structure by nesting a series of for XML PATH statements:

```
SELECT  CustomerID AS 'CustomerID' ,
        CustomerName AS 'CustomerName' ,
        ( SELECT    ( SELECT    PhoneNumber AS 'PhoneNumber' ,
                                PhoneType AS 'PhoneType'
                      FROM      Phone
                      WHERE     Phone.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID
                    FOR
                      XML PATH('Phone') ,
                          TYPE
                    )
        FOR
          XML PATH('Phones') ,
              TYPE
        )
FROM    Customer
FOR     XML PATH('Customer') ,
            TYPETYPE
```

Comment: Code is untested but mirrors the model I used for the actual data.